# Postfix selectively bypassing the spam

Tags: centos, postfix, spam, spam-filter

**I have Centos 7 installed and postfix as MTA on the server. Here is my anti spam postfix additional configuration:**

```
# main.cf ANTI SPAM
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes

smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
   reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
   reject_invalid_hostname,
   permit

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   reject_invalid_hostname,
   reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
   reject_non_fqdn_sender,
   reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
   reject_unknown_sender_domain,
   reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
   permit_mynetworks,
   reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
   reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
   reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
   reject_rbl_client recent.spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
   reject_rbl_client spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
   reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
   reject_rbl_client ubl.unsubscore.com,
   reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,
   permit

smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 10
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 60
```

It really works and filters any possible spam attempts, unfortunatelly I faced to the unpredictable behaviour of postfix exactly in Spam Black Lists lookup by reject_rbl_client.

## /var/log/maillog

Spamer IP 122.172.50.104 listed in SBL and mail filtered by postfix

```
Feb  9 07:24:09 lax postfix/smtpd[20209]: connect from unknown[122.172.50.104]
Feb  9 07:24:10 lax postfix/smtpd[20209]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[122.172.50.104]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [122.172.50.104] blocked using dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net; Dynamic IP Addresses See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?122.172.50.104; from=<canadian-drugstore8@airtelbroadband.in> to=<MYEMAIL> proto=ESMTP helo=<abts-kk-dynamic-104.50.172.122.airtelbroadband.in>
Feb  9 07:24:11 lax postfix/smtpd[20209]: lost connection after RCPT from unknown[122.172.50.104]
Feb  9 07:24:11 lax postfix/smtpd[20209]: disconnect from unknown[122.172.50.104]
```

Spamer IP 66.199.240.242 this ip listed in several Black lists that **also included in my postfix configuration** but mail has not been filtered by Postfix. Why? Postfix has broken lookup links to SBL or what?

```
Feb  8 16:17:37 lax postfix/smtpd[10346]: connect from m1.churneo.eu[66.199.240.242]
Feb  8 16:17:38 lax postfix/smtpd[10346]: DD95A101CE93D: client=m1.churneo.eu[66.199.240.242]
Feb  8 16:17:41 lax postfix/cleanup[10351]: DD95A101CE93D: message-id=<a13d21eb0e2582e91d1993a8b8ae43@HoeHOdGArAal.R1.CHurNeO.eu>
Feb  8 16:17:42 lax postfix/qmgr[7998]: DD95A101CE93D: from=<bounces+c11978i204195321b19047u25533832+MYUSER=MYDIOMAIN@HoeHOdGArAal.R1.CHurNeO.eu>, size=26 401, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  8 16:17:42 lax postfix/local[10353]: DD95A101CE93D: to=<MYEMAIL>, orig_to=<MYEMAIL>, relay=local, delay=4.2, delays=4.2/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Feb  8 16:17:42 lax postfix/qmgr[7998]: DD95A101CE93D: removed
Feb  8 16:17:42 lax postfix/smtpd[10346]: disconnect from m1.churneo.eu[66.199.240.242]
```

Here is my manual SBL checking online tools:

```
1. http://rblcheck.at/
2. http://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php
3. http://www.tcpiputils.com/dns-blackhole-list
```

**My question is:** How does the postfix actually works to get spam confirmation by the reject_rbl_client directive? How could I fix my configuration to make it function properly?

Comment: The checks in your postfix config and the tools you are using to validate manually are not the same.  IP's will usually drop out of the RBL's after a week or two of not being reported.  If you check manually in each of the sites you listed, using the rbl sites in your main.cf, what do you see?

Comment: Also, you can save yourself a lot of RBL DNS lookups by rejecting people that don't have FCrDNS.  After your `permit_mynetworks,` add a line with `regexp:/etc/postfix/postfix_client_blacklist,`  then in that postfix_client_blacklist file, add `/^unknown$/    REJECT FCrDNS`